# Play! framework: can I reschedule the job?

Tags: playframework, scheduler, jobs, playframework-1.x

I'm using Play! framwork of version 1.2.4
In my application, I have implemented a number of scheduled jobs (descendants of `play.jobs.Job`).

#### Question

Can I change the schedule of these jobs at runtime?

#### My own findings

At first glance, the job scheduling in Play! is done via `play.jobs.JobsPlugin`, which in turn uses JDK's `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instance which is publicly exposed. So far I came up with following approach: when it's the moment to change schedule, I simply iterate over executor' scheduled jobs, cancel one which I need to reschedule and schedule the same job (more precisely, the job of the same class) with new settings. Something like this:

```java
for (final Object o: JobsPlugin.executor.getQueue())
{
    ScheduledFuture task = (ScheduledFuture) o;
    Job job = (Job) Java.extractUnderlyingCallable((FutureTask)task);
    if (MyJob.class == job.getClass())
    {
        task.cancel(true);
        new MyJob().every("2h");
        break;
    }
}
```

Are there any better solutions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your solution works because when you look at JobsPlugin call, it recalculates Job next planned execution date at the end of each job execution.

Here is my solution, I recreate a JobScheduler class to be able to calculate job execution date based on a cron attribute of my job. I had to redeclare some jobs attributes because of visibility rules.

So my job class is

```
package jobs;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

import play.jobs.Job;

public class MyJob extends Job<Object> {

    public Date nextPlannedExecution = null;
    public String cron = null;

    @Override
    public void _finally() {
        // cron is null if we force job execution
        if (cron != null) {
            // As the job don't have a Cron annotation, super call does nothing
            super._finally();
            JobScheduler.scheduleForCRON(this, cron);
        }
    }

    void setExecutor(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }
}
```

And my scheduler class is
    package jobs;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import models.Partner;
import play.Logger;
import play.jobs.Job;
import play.jobs.JobsPlugin;
import play.libs.Expression;
import play.libs.Time.CronExpression;

public class JobScheduler {

    public static synchronized void scheduleCsvExportJob(String cron) {
        MyJob myJob = null;
        for (Job<?> job : JobsPlugin.scheduledJobs) {
            if (job instanceof MyJob) {
                myJob = (MyJob) job;
            }
        }
        if (myJob == null) {
            myJob = new MyJob();
            JobsPlugin.scheduledJobs.add(myJob);
        }
        myJob.cron = cron;
        scheduleForCRON(myJob, myJob.cron);
    }

    public static void scheduleForCRON(MyJob job, String cron) {
        try {
            Date now = new Date();
            cron = Expression.evaluate(cron, cron).toString();
            CronExpression cronExp = new CronExpression(cron);
            Date nextDate = cronExp.getNextValidTimeAfter(now);
            if (nextDate != null && !nextDate.equals(job.nextPlannedExecution)) {
                job.nextPlannedExecution = nextDate;
                JobsPlugin.executor.schedule((Callable<?>) job, nextDate.getTime() - now.getTime(),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                job.setExecutor(JobsPlugin.executor);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.error(ex, "Cannot schedule job %s", job);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, you can call JobScheduler.scheduleMyJob to change the scheduling of the job by passing the right scheduling expression : 0 0 2 * * ? for every 2 hours.

When the job terminates, the _finally method will recall the scheduleForCRON method which set the new scheduling time.

If you want to force execution of the job, for example through a gui button, you can create an instance without cron attribute define and this instance won't reschedule itselft at the end