# Play Jobs with multiple schedules

Tags: playframework, cron, jobs, playframework-1.x

Is there a way with Play 1 to have multiple schedules for the same job?

I would like one of my job to run at certain times daily and different times at the week ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now it wasn't possible to have the same job with different schedule altough the work around described by Seb would do the trick.

However there is now a new module called [Multi Jobs](http://www.playmodules.net/module/32) which allows to have several methods defined with their own schedule.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some kind of manual schedule like this [Play! framework: can I reschedule the job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538170/play-framework-can-i-reschedule-the-job/12559450#12559450)

But this may be overkilled for what you want. I think for you the best is to have two jobs with two different crons and each one call a common util method that do the common job.

The other solution is to schedule all the hours (both weekday and weekends) and test in your job what kind of day you are and do the job or not based on this check